# How to effect classes starting with common classes?

Tags: css, html

I have so many classes starting with test that are like test-1,test-2,test-3 etc and under that class div anchor link with class as work. How can effect with css. Below is my work around.

```
<div class="test-1"><a class="work">test content</a></div>
```

Above is code: and tried with below css. Not working.

```
div[class^="test-"] a.work {float:left;clear:both;}
```

Comment: This may be helpful http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly valid and works fine as you can see in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/JmHvz/

However, the best/cleanest/fastest solution would be adding an additional class such as `test` (i.e. `<div class="test test-1">`) and use that one in your CSS (`div.test a.work { ... }`) since a class selector is *always* going to be faster than a generic attribute selector - especially in modern browsers which most likely have a mapping from class names to elements since it's a rather common thing.

Comment: Where i need to add extra test class?

Comment: That I know, But data coming as dynamic..means classes are generating dynamically as technology is CMS